# Storing JSON into database in python

Tags: python, json

I'm fetching some data from an API on regular interval and wants to store the JSON data into database to access and use later.

From API, I get data in this sample each time:

```
'{"data": {"cursor": null, "files": {"nodes": [{u'code': u'BOPhmYQg5Vm', u'date': 1482244678,u'counts': 2, u'id': u'1409492981312099686'}, {u'code': u'g5VmBOPhmYQ', u'date': 1482244678,u'counts': 5, u'id': u'1209968614094929813'}]}}}'
```

I can `json_data = json.loads(above_data)` and then fetch `nodes` as `nodes_data = json_data["data"]["files"]["nodes"]` which gives a list of `nodes`.

I want to store this `nodes` data into DB column `data = Column(db.Text)` of `Text` type. Each time there are going to be 10-15 values in nodes list.

How do I store? There are multiple `nodes` and I need it in a way that in future I can append/add more `nodes` to already available `data` column in my db.

While I would like to do `json.loads(db_data_col)` so that I get valid json and can loop over all of `nodes` to get internal data and use later.

I'm confused on how to store in db and access later in valid json format.

**Edit 1:** Using Sqlite for testing. Can use PostgresSQL in future. `Text` type of column is main point.

Comment: You didn't mentioned the database in which you want to store. Implementation is dependent on database type. Also, if you'll google *write json data source to <database-type>*, you will get what you are looking for

Comment: What sort of database are you using? Most will allow you to dumb the JSON contents as a string into a Text field. Postgres has a dedicated JSON type, where you can store JSON data directly in a field. Others have at least special operators to handle JSON data.

Comment: If it has to be a single node like {"name": "hey", "count": 1}, I can blindly use json.loads/dumps. My concern is lots of nodes and appending more in future.

Comment: Are you using Django as your framework? If so, which version? Django 1.9+ has JSON as a model field.

Comment: Django 1.9 json field documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield

Comment: If you just want to store and retrieve the json data and not use sqlite to manipulate it you can just put it into a blob.

Comment: I use TinyDB for a JSON-type db storage, take a look at this project at how it queries and inserts into TinyDB https://gitlab.com/perfecto25/silica/blob/master/app/views/db/__init__.py https://gitlab.com/perfecto25/silica/blob/master/app/views/db/generator.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to store JSON data into DB. Since I'm accessing `nodes` from remote service which returns a `list` of nodes on every request, I need to build proper json to store/retrieve from db.

Say API returned json text as : `'{"cursor": null, "nodes" = [{"name": "Test1", "value: 1}, {"name": "Test2", "value: 2}, ...]}'`

So, first we need to access nodes list as:

```
data = json.loads(api_data)
nodes = data['nodes']
```

Now for 1st entry into DB column we need to do following:

`str_data = json.dumps({"nodes": nodes})`

So, `str_data` would return a valid string/buffer, which we can store into DB with a `"nodes"` key.

For 2nd or successive entries into DB column, we will do following:

```
# get data string from DB column and load into json
db_data = json.loads(db_col_data)
# get new/latest 'nodes' data from api as explained above
# append this data to 'db_data' json as
latest_data = db_data["nodes"] + new_api_nodes
# now add this data back to column after json.dumps()
db_col_data = json.dumps(latest_data)
# add to DB col and DB commit
```

It is a proper way to load/dump data from DB while adding/removing json and keeping proper format.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Django 1.8 you can create your own model field that can store a json. This class will make sure that you have the right JSON format as well.

```
import json
from django.db import models

class JsonField(models.TextField):
    """
    Stores json-able python objects as json.
    """
    def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
        try:
            return json.dumps(value)
        except TypeError:
            BAD_DATA.error(
                "cannot serialize %s to store in a JsonField", str(value)
            )
            return ""

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection, context):
        if value == "":
            return None
        try:
            return json.loads(value)
        except TypeError:
            BAD_DATA.error("cannot load dictionary field -- type error")
            return None
```

Comment: Nope, Django is not required.